# How to access my php page in wordpress

Tags: customization

I created a services folder in `wordpress/wp-content/services`. This folder will have web services coded in PHP. But when i try to access the `.php` file it is being redirected to `index.html`

While checking the `.htaccess` file i came across the line `# ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` even though i commented the line the problem is still same.

Is there any particular standard to be followed to access my php.
I also tried including `require_once(wp-load())` but no use..

please help..
thanks

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot access the `.php` files in this folder directly. You can put all your services code in a plugin and install it. That way it is better...

Comment: So i must start creating custom plugin here! But, i did the same on another server, It worked fine there.

Answer (score -1):

The only way I can think of attempting this would be to have a custom page template that will pull in various bits of your custom PHP via get_template_part